# Why the memory allocation failed when passing the pointer as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, heap-memory

I just tried two piece of code to allocate contiguous memory for a 2D array and use g++ to compile the code. The second piece of code works well but the fisrt one will lead to Segmentation fault (core dumped). What's wrong with the first piece of code and why they are different.

Thanks for your help!

```
void mem_alloc2D(double **U, unsigned Nx, unsigned Ny) {
    U = new double*[Nx];
    U[0] = new double[Nx*Ny];
    for (unsigned r = 1; r < Nx; ++r)
        U[r] = U[0] + r*Ny;
}

double **mem_alloc2D(unsigned Nx, unsigned Ny) {
    double **U;
    U = new double*[Nx];
    U[0] = new double[Nx*Ny];
    for (unsigned r = 1; r < Nx; ++r)
        U[r] = U[0] + r*Ny;
    return U;
}
```

Comment: In the first one, you are passing `U` by value. The modified value of `U` is not visible to the calling function.

Comment: Two calls to `new` cannot possibly allocate contiguous memory.

Comment: A value pointed at is passed by reference. The pointer itself is still passed by value, so the address stored in the pointer is merely a copy of the pointer used as a source. They have the same address, point to the same place, but only until you change the copy to point elsewhere.

Comment: Another trick to handle this (and also the pointer-chase Neil's warning about):https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Comment: Why the down votes and votes to close? This question is very clear and contains code that produces the problem.

Comment: Thanks all of you, I'm really puzzled why I always got down voted in this platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first snippet you pass the double pointer by value. So when you invoke `mem_alloc2D(p, Nx, Ny)`  the pointer `p` that you pass is not "updated" at the exit from the function. Passing the pointer by reference

```
void mem_alloc2D(double** &U, unsigned Nx, unsigned Ny)
```

should make it work.

In the second snippet you return a newly created pointer, so it works fine.